# Why does `allowJS` cause an unwanted `src` subdirectory in my compiled output?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, tsconfig

I'm converting a legacy node/express codebase to TypeScript, following the [Microsoft TypeScript starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter) as a starting reference.

In this reference output is compiled to `dist`, however when enabling `allowJS` in `tsconfig.json`, the output is emitted to `dist/src` - why is that?

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es6",
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "rootDir" : "./",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "allowJs": true,
  "paths": {
    "*": [
      "node_modules/*",
      "src/types/*"
    ]
  }
},
"include": [
  "src/**/*"
]
```

}

- I tried changing `rootDir` to `./src` but it gives an error saying 'node_modules/someModule' is not in the src root.
- I tried moving `tsconfig.json` to src, according to a GitHub issue I saw, but no output was generated.

**AllowJS**

The output was mapping correctly under `/dist` until `allowJS` flag was turned on in `tsconfig.json`, after which output appeared in `/dist/src`

Comment: Try specifying your source as `files: [ "src/index.js" ]`. See if that helps

Comment: Thanks @unional. Will be tricky to do that, as I have hundreds of them. Would have to generate a build script. Looking for a simple solution, or at least an explanation, initially.

Comment: @JasperBlues you can also use `include: ["src/**"]`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you, I have that already. I'll update the question with that info.

Comment: One problem I spot is your `rootDir`. That tells tsc to have src in your output path.

Comment: @unional I've detailed what happens when I set `rootDit` to `src` - it causes compile errors. It looks as though `allowJS` is ignoring excludes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

- Typescript relies on `rootDir` to decide the directory structure of the output (see [this comment from Typescript's bossman](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9858#issuecomment-370537216)).
- Only code within the `rootDir` can be compiled/emitted by `tsc`.
- If you don't set `rootDir` explicitly, it defaults to `./` (relative to tsconfig)... **unless you've included something outside of `./`** that needs to be compiled/emitted by `tsc`, in which case it forces `rootDir` to automatically get set to the directory that contains all the source.
- The `allowJS` setting tells `tsc` to treat `.js` code as source and to also emit it to the `outDir`.

I suspect that when you enabled `allowJS`, there was `.js` code outside of `src` that tsc now had to emit to `outDir`, and so it automatically moved `rootDir` one level up. Since `src` is now a subdir of the `rootDir`, this gets mirrored within `outDir`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467483/8910547) for a solution that enables you to have `src` remain a rootDir and also include code from outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your compiler (TSC) config file may be up a level from where you want the transpiler to begin the linking process. Can you try pushing it down a level and let us know what happens?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for late acceptance. From memory, this was the solution.

Comment: @JasperBlues This cannot be what solved it for you, **given the two bullets at the end of your question!** I'll type up an alternate answer.