# 'package.json' is not under 'rootDir'

Tags: javascript, typescript, package.json, tsconfig

I'm trying to import `package.json` in my TypeScript application:

```
import packageJson from '../package.json';
```

My `tsconfig.json` contains the following:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src/"
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I compile this, I get

> `error TS6059: File '/path/to/package.json' is not under 'rootDir' '/path/to/app/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

I'm not sure I understand the issue, because both `./src/` and `./dist/` have the same parent `..`, so TypeScript could just leave alone the `import '../package.json'` and **it would work** from either `rootDir` or `outDir`.

Anyway, I've tried the following, with unsatisfactory results:

- remove `rootDir` - compilation works, but the `dist` will contain `dist/src`, which I don't want
- remove `outDir` - then `src` gets polluted with `.js` files (and `.js.map` if `sourceMap` was true)
- add `@ts-ignore` - compilation stops the the file that imports `../package.json`

What's the workaround for this limitation, to keep generated files in `dist`, and allow importing from the parent directory of `rootDir`?

Comment: Does `// @ts-ignore` help?

Comment: I’m having the same issue. Adding `// @ts-ignore` doesn’t help.

Comment: the given `import` statement doesn't jive with the given `tsconfig`. Produces error. See my suggested edit.

Comment: Did you tried to set `baseUrl` instead of `rootDir`?

Comment: I found this can work if you just use `require` instead of `import`. Of course this assumes you're on the node platform. And when distributing the package you're not distributing `dist` but the entire directory containing `package.json`.

Answer (score 114):

This is **possible**, and it turns out, **not hard**.

The reason the solution is **not obvious** is because Typescript relies on the `rootDir` to decide the directory structure of the output (see [this comment from Typescript's bossman](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9858#issuecomment-370537216)), and only code included in the output or in package dependencies can be imported.

- If you set `rootDir` to the root of your project, `package.json` gets emitted to the root of `outDir` and can be imported. But then your compiled `src` files get written to `outDir/src`.
- If you set `rootDir` to `src`, files in there will compile to the root of `outDir`.  But now [the compiler won't have a place to emit `package.json`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9858#issuecomment-533230402), so it issues "an error because the project appears to be misconfigured" (bossman's words).

### solution: *use separate Typescript sub-projects*

Each Typescript *project* is self-contained, defined by its own `tsconfig`, with its own `rootDir`. This lines up with the principle of **encapsulation**.

You can have multiple projects (e.g. a main and a set of libs) each in their own `rootDir` and with their own tsconfig.  Dependencies between them are declared in the dependent's `tsconfig` using Typescript [Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html).

> I admit, the term "projects" is a poor one, as intuitively it refers to the whole shebang, but "modules" and "packages" are already taken. Think of them as *subprojects* and it will make more sense.

To solve your specific problem, we'll treat the `src` directory and the root directory containing `package.json` as separate projects. Each will have its own `tsconfig`.

1. Give the `src` dir its own project.

   **`./src/tsconfig.json`**:

   ```json
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "rootDir": ".",
       "outDir": "../dist/",
       "resolveJsonModule": true
     },
     "references": [      // this is how we declare a dependency from
       { "path": "../" }  // this project to the one at the root dir`
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Give the root dir its own project.

   **`./tsconfig.json`**:

   ```json
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "rootDir": ".",
       "outDir": ".",  // if out path for a file is same as its src path, nothing will be emitted
       "resolveJsonModule": true,
       "composite": true  // required on the dependency project for references to work
     },
     "files": [         // by whitelisting the files to include, you avoid the default TS behavior, which
       "package.json"   // will include everything, resulting in `src` being included in both projects (bad)
     ]
   }
   ```
3. run `tsc --build src` and voilà!

   This will build the `src` project. Because it declares a reference to the root project, it will build that one also, but only if it is out of date. Because the root tsconfig has the same dir as the `outDir`, tsc will simply do nothing to `package.json` , the one file it is configured to compile.

### this is great for monorepos

- You can isolate modules/libraries/sub-projects by putting them in their own subdirectory and giving them their own tsconfig.
- You can manage dependencies explicitly using [Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html), as well as modularize the build:

  From the linked doc:

  - you can greatly improve build times

    > A long-awaited feature is smart incremental builds for TypeScript projects. In 3.0 you can use the `--build`flag with `tsc`. This is effectively a new entry point for `tsc` that behaves more like a build orchestrator than a simple compiler.
    >
    > Running `tsc --build` (`tsc -b` for short) will do the following:
    >
    > - Find all referenced projects
    > - Detect if they are up-to-date
    > - Build out-of-date projects in the correct order

    > Don’t worry about ordering the files you pass on the commandline - `tsc` will re-order them if needed so that dependencies are always built first.
  - **enforce logical separation between components**
  - organize your code in new and better ways.

It's also very easy:

1. A root `tsconfig` for shared options and to build all
   subprojects with a simple `tsc --build` command
   (with `--force` to build them from scratch)

   **`src/tsconfig.json`**

   ```json
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "outDir": ".", // prevents this tsconfig from compiling any files

       // we want subprojects to inherit these options:
       "target": "ES2019", 
       "module": "es2020", 
       "strict": true,
       ...
     },

     // configure this project to build all of the following:
     "references": [
       { "path": "./common" }
       { "path": "./projectA" }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. A "common" library that is prevented from importing from the
   other subprojects because it has no project references

   **`src/common/tsconfig.json`**

   ```json
   {
     "extends": "../tsconfig.json", //inherit from root tsconfig

     // but override these:
     "compilerOptions": {
       "rootDir": ".",
       "outDir": "../../build/common",
       "resolveJsonModule": true,
       "composite": true
     }
   }
   ```
3. A subproject that can import *common* because of the declared reference.
   **`src/projectA/tsconfig.json`**

   ```json
   {
     "extends": "../tsconfig.json", //inherit from root tsconfig

     // but override these:
     "compilerOptions": {
       "rootDir": ".",
       "outDir": "../../build/libA",
       "resolveJsonModule": true,
       "composite": true
     },
     "references": [
       { "path": "../common" }
     ]
   }
   ```

Comment: @DanDascalescu let me know if I answered you question about monorepos.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! The other one was slightly simpler for my use case so I awarded the bounty, but thanks for reminding me about the [monorepo granular access solution with subtrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408829/granular-access-to-directories-within-monorepo/61273621#61273621) - accepted!

Comment: @DanDascalescu  My pleasure. I need to figure this stuff out for myself anyway. You of course know your needs better than I, but as to "simpler"... consider the advantages that `tsc --build` offers that you'll miss out on. See [the bottom of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61470720/8910547) (the top is much the same, though the tsconfigs are correct... I missed some details above which I'll fix for future readers).

Comment: This breaks missing import and unused import features in vscode for me:  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38605

Comment: @SephReed let's see what they come back with on the Issue report. Type checking on *used* imports work correctly?

Comment: This is a super helpful and clear answer - it should be included in the Typescript docs, which are not as clear as this.

Comment: @crimbo so flattered! thank you!

Comment: Many thanks to you. I've been having issues even finding documentation that hints at these concepts. You've done a great job of making things clear.

Comment: @LanceGliser glad it was helpful! I just reread my answer, and was wondering if `2. Give the root dir its own project.` would be less confusing if it read `Give project.json its own project.`?  The former is more technically correct, since `tsconfig` applies to the dir tree rooted at its location, but because we've whitelisted only `project.json` with the `files` property, the latter is effectively correct: a project for that one file. Thoughts?

Comment: First, thanks for the great answer!  Second, I'm trying to follow your monorepo example with a TypeScript project that has server, client, and common "subprojects" (for now I'm just using common and server).  My setup is VERY similar to your example (though each project has its own src folder), but when I run `tsc --build client/tsconfig.json` I get an error like this: "Cannot write file '/build/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo' because it will overwrite '.tsbuildinfo' file generated by referenced project '/common'."  Any clues?

Comment: @FTLPhysicsGuy First, Thanks! Second, check out https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30925#issuecomment-491026990. Seems you'll have to tweak your config to adjust where `tsbuildinfo` will go for each of your subprojects, since by default they all go to the same location. `tsbuildinfo`, btw, is where ts keeps incremental compile info, which is why there is one per subproject. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: @Inigo Thanks for the link -- that's just what I was looking for.  As my friends and I say, my google-fu was weak.  As it turns out, I ended up re-arranging my project to use a single src directory with projects under it (matching your example) and the problem, of course, went away.  It's nice to know there's a way to go back to the original structure if I wanted.  Problem solved!

Comment: @FTLPhysicsGuy My current monorepo project doesn't use a `src` dir at all. Each component's non-test source is in its own directory at the root of the repo, with all tests under a root `test` dir. I think that works because all my tests are written in JS, not TS (intentional).

Comment: Just wanted to express my appreciation for this answer. Superb contribution, thanks!

Comment: Thanks mate! I was about to open an issue on typescript's repo.

Answer (score 29):

We can set `resolveJsonModule` to false and declare a module for `*.json` inside `typings.d.ts` which will require JSON files as modules and it will generate files without any directory structure inside the `dist` directory.

### Monorepo directory structure

```
monorepo\
├─ app\
│  ├─ src\
│  │  └─ index.ts
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ tsconfig.json
│  └─ typings.d.ts
└─ lib\
   └─ package.json
```

### `app/typings.d.ts`

```ts
declare module "*.json";
```

### `app/src/index.ts`

```ts
// Import from app/package.json
import appPackageJson from '../package.json';

// Import from lib/package.json
import libPackageJson from '../../lib/package.json';

export function run(): void {
  console.log(`App name "${appPackageJson.name}" with version ${appPackageJson.version}`);
  console.log(`Lib name "${libPackageJson.name}" with version ${libPackageJson.version}`);  
}

run();
```

### `app/package.json` contents

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  ...
}
```

### `lib/package.json` contents

```json
{
  "name": "my-lib",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  ...
}
```

Now if we compile the project using `tsc`, we'll get the following `dist` directory structure:

```
app\
└─ dist\
   ├─ index.d.ts
   └─ index.js
```

And if we run it using `node ./dist`, we'll get the output from both `app` and `lib` `package.json` information:

```
$ node ./dist
App name "my-app" with version 0.0.1
Lib name "my-lib" with version 1.0.1
```

You can find the project repository here: https://github.com/clytras/typescript-monorepo

Comment: upvoted. between [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467483/8910547) and yours we have two legit solutions :)

Comment: Simplest answer, so I'll award it the bounty. Thanks! The only, very minor, issue I see is a warning for `value` in `typings.d.ts`: `A default export can only be used in an ECMAScript-style module`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu thank you for the bounty. Where do you get that warning, when you try to import the modules, or maybe when running using `ts-node`? It would be very helpful if you can PR an example that causing that warning to the repository so I can further investigate it.

Comment: Might be from [WebStorm](https://github.com/clytras/typescript-monorepo/issues/2)?

Comment: Yes it might, I don't see that warning in latest VSCode that uses `TS 3.8.3`. I'll check this out to find out if it's related to the WebStorm or to the TS version that WS is using.

Comment: I've tried this for a `lib.common.ts` file in `../../` but I still got the `file ../../common.ts not under 'rootDir'` error. Is this `declare module '*.json'` trick limited to JSON files? I used `declare module '*.common.ts'` in the same `typings.d.ts` file. What I'm trying to do is share this `lib.common.ts` between a `backend` and a `website` directories in a monorepo.

Comment: Your solutions always works properly. thanks alot.

Comment: In my situation, I need to put `typings.d.ts` into the `/src` folder

Answer (score 10):

There is a tidy three-step solution with Node 16+ LTS and TypeScript 4.7+ for packages that use [ES modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) instead of CommonJS.

The [`"imports"` field](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports) in **package.json** defines internal pseudo-packages that can be imported only from within your actual package. Define an internal import specifier, such as `#package.json` in **package.json**:

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "exports": "./dist/index.js",
  "imports": {
    "#package.json": "./package.json"
  }
}
```

Enable [TypeScript support for ES modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html) and JSON imports in **tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "nodenext",
    // "moduleResolution" defaults to "nodenext", just made explicit here
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  }
}
```

Lastly, [import `#package.json`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#json-modules) from your TypeScript module:

```
import packageJson from '#package.json' assert { type: 'json' };

console.log(packageJson);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for now. Typescript compiler try to keep your directory structure.

For example, your project look like:

```
src/
  shared/
    index.ts
  index.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

Your `tsconfig.json` contains:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

As you see, the file does not include `rootDir` property, but when you call `tsc` command to compile the project, the output will look like:

```
build/
  shared/
    index.js
  index.js
```

The output does not contain `src` folder, because in my code, I just import and use inside `src` folder, like:

`src/index.ts`

```
import someName from './shared';
```

then, `build/index.js` will look like:

```
...
const shared_1 = __importDefault(require("./shared"));
...
```

as you see - `require("./shared")`, this mean it working fine with `build` folder structure.

Your "issue" appeared when you import a "outside" module

```
import packageJson from '../package.json';
```

So, what happen with "back" action - '../'? If you hope your output structure will be:

```
build/
  package.json
  index.js
```

then, how do they work with `const packageJson = __importDefault(require("../package.json"));`. Then Typescript compiler try to keep project structure:

```
build/
  package.json
  src/
    index.js
```

With a monorepo project, I think you need to create declaration files for each library, end then use `references` setting in the tsconfig file. Ex:

1. In the `./lib01` folder, the lib import `./lib02` in their code. Tsconfig file will be like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "references": [ // here
    {
      "path": "../lib02"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. lib02's `tsconfig.json`

```
 {
   "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "composite": true // importance.
  }
 }
```

Comment: I was thinking that since `src/index.ts` imports `../package.json`, TypeScript can simply keep the same path, change nothing, and generate `dest/index.js` with the same `import '../package.json'`. (I use `esnext` modules, but that doesn't matter.). Both `src` and `dest` have the same parent, so `..` will resolve to the same directory.

Comment: ['Tis totally possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467483/8910547)!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how and when you're reading "package.json". You can read it as file with NodeJS "fs" module at runtime, or just type const package = require("package.json").

In 2nd case Typescript will search it in root dir at compile time (refer to [Typescript module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) documentation).

You also can use "rootDirs" property instead of "rootDir" to specify array of root folders.

Comment: const package = require("../package.json") solved the issue for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using `// @ts-ignore` on top of the `import` call and setting `"rootDir": "./src"` it works. In this case enabling `resolveJsonModule` will still work, but only for files under the `./src`. See: https://github.com/MatrixAI/TypeScript-Demo-Lib/pull/33 for how I applied it to our template repository. This way it is possible to import json files from within `./src` as normal, but when you import `../package.json`, you have to use `// @ts-ignore` to ensure that TSC ignores it. It's a one-off special case so this works.

The reason it all works is because
setting https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDir will force tsc not to infer the project root dir to be the src. And thus will enforce the expected `dist` structure, while throwing warnings/errors on importing outside the `rootDir`. But you can ignore these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-require-imports
const packageJson = require('../package.json');
```

Answer (score -2):

I solve this problem by using symlink:
in windows:

```
cd src
mklink package.json ..\package.json
```

or in linux:

```
cd src
ln -s package.json ../package.json
```