# Extend a "paths" tsconfig file for a monorepo

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, monorepo

I've got a folder structure like so:

```
- mono-repo
  tsconfig.paths.json
  - Website
   tsconfig.json
   - src
     test.ts
     index.ts
  - Tool
   - src
    index.ts
```

```js
// mono-repo/tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "tool": ["Tool/src"],
    }
  }
}
```

```
// mono-repo/Website/src/index.ts
import { test } from "test";
import { tool } from "tool";

test(tool);
```

I'd like to be able to extend `tsconfig.paths.json` so that every package has correctly typed module imports for the others.

---

**Failed Attempt 1**

```js
// mono-repo/Website/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
  }
}
```

*Issue:* can not find module "tool".  The baseUrl added to the path leads to `mono-repo/Website/src/Tool/src`.  This is not a real path.

---

**Failed Attempt 2**

```js
// mono-repo/Website/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../",
  }
}
```

*Issue:* can not import test from "test".  The baseUrl is not the project src.  Anything but relative paths will be unexportable.

---

**Functional but Ugly Attempt 3**

```js
// mono-repo/tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "tool": ["../../Tool/src"],
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// mono-repo/Website/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
  }
}
```

*Issue:* works, but makes the assumption that the baseUrl of every tsconfig which extends tsconfig.paths.json will always be two directories below `mono-repo`.  This is currently true for my project, but I'm hesitant to make this a standard.

---

**How does one set up an extendable "paths" tsconfig json for a monorepo?**

Comment: You should use Project References. See [the second half of this answer, under "this is great for monorepos"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467483/8910547)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something to know is that tsconfig extends is an `override` and `not a merge`.
With that information, you can understand that what you are trying to achieve by extending the base tsconfig can't work as you expecting it to do.

Also, using the `paths` options should always work as a pair with the `baseUrl` in order to solve the resolution problem.

Nonetheless, here is a solution that you can use to solve that problem.

create a tsconfig.json at the root level of your project alongs the line of:

```
"paths": {
  "~/*": ["../../../mono-repo/*/src"]
}
```

Which means in each sub packages, you can extends that `tsconfig` file and then specify your `src` directory as a `baseUrl`. Then you will be able to import as follow:

```
import { tool } from "~/Tool";
```

Hope that it is clear, let me know if something is missing =)

Comment: It's not working for me. Typescript still raises the issue of "Cannot find module 
 or its corresponding type declarations."

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly it is about `create-react-app`. If so then you need multiple folder like `src` in the repo root directory. This require configure webpack so to avoid eject use rewire and use [alias](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-rewire-alias) for multiple top level directory:

```js
// config-overrides.js:

const {alias, configPaths} = require('react-app-rewire-alias')

module.exports = function override(config) {
  alias(configPaths())(config)
  return config
}
```