# TypeScript build isolated modules completely separately

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a bunch of JavaScript scripts that I want to improve using JSDoc and TypeScript Typings

I need to be able to compile them absolutely independently so the code from one script doesn't mess up the typing system in the other script.

###### script1.d.ts

```js
export {};

declare global {
    var myGlobalVariable: {
        property1: {
            childProperty1: string;
        }
    }
}
```

###### script2.d.ts

```js
export {};

declare global {
    var myGlobalVariable: {
        property1: {
            childProperty2: string;
        }
    }
}
```

###### script1.js

```js
/// <reference path="script1.d.ts" />

console.log(myGlobalVariable.property1.childProperty1);
```

###### script2.js

```js
/// <reference path="script2.d.ts" />

console.log(myGlobalVariable.property1.childProperty2);
```

###### tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "isolatedModules": true
    },
    "include": [
        "*.js"
    ]
}
```

Executing

```
> tsc
```

I am getting the errors

```
script2.d.ts(4,9): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'myGlobalVariable' must be of type '{ property1: { childProperty1: string; }; }', but here has type '{ property1: { childProperty2: string; }; }'.
script2.js(3,40): error TS2551: Property 'childProperty2' does not exist on type '{ childProperty1: string; }'. Did you mean 'childProperty1'?
```

Is there a way to configure TypeScript to build my isolated modules indeed in an isolated way?

Additionally I prepared a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mnaoumov/7db6e73c5872b8c286bc812e6ad62c81) with all those files mentioned above.

###### UPD

Also raised the same [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55315) in the TypeScript repo

###### UPD2

To clarify confusions I will provide more context why do I need such architecture.

I am using [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) note-taking app with the [Dataview](https://github.com/blacksmithgu/obsidian-dataview) plugin.

This plugin allows to execute custom JavaScript

````
```dataviewjs
await dv.view('script1');
```
````

which will invoke abovementioned `script1.js`

Internally Dataview executes `script1.js` by reading its content and `eval`s it.

Naturally, `script1.js` and `script2.js` are executed and `eval`ed independently and have no shared context.

Comment: Put them in different projects with separate tsconfig files. Or do not use tsconfig at all but pass the file names explicitly to `tsc`. In any case, you'll need to run `tsc` separately for each, with different includes.

Comment: @Bergi I am hoping there is a solution that can fit in my current project architecture

Comment: This isn't isolating the globals, but you can certainly fix the type checking your by making the type of `property1` an interface. Therefore, it's declarations will be merged.

Comment: @mnaoumov This doesn't make sense. You *have* two projects, otherwise the globals would collide if the scripts ran in the same environment. So: why?

Comment: @Bergi Because `script1.js` and `script2.js` are used independently and executed at different times. Consider them as plugins invoked only when appropriate

Comment: @AluanHaddad No, I don't want to merge the definitions. In the context when `script2.js` is invoked, the property `childProperty1` doesn't exist at all

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what you're trying to do anymore. Module isolation applies to modules, not to scripts. Isolating your scripts isn't a thing if they contribute to the same application. Furthermore, declarations within modules which explicitly augment the global scope exist explicitly to escape the encapsulation of modules.

Comment: @mnaoumov I hope your application makes sure never to load both plugins at once :-) Anyway, independent plugins sound very much like separate projects to me.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your questions, I provided an UPD to my post explaining better my use case

Comment: "*Naturally, script1.js and script2.js are executed and evaled independently and have no shared context.*" - not sure how that comes naturally, what if you use both in a dataview on the same page? I don't know anything about obsidian-dataview, but the docs don't mention it (or anything about iframes or the like). Even if you tried it, I wouldn't take that behaviour as a given.

Comment: Anyway, to stop complaining and be more constructive: take a look at [the `tsc` cli options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). You can it on an individual file, without using a tsconfig.json; or you can use two separate tsconfig files (with different include paths) and point `tsc` at them. But as said before, you must run `tsc` multiple times, there's no way to do this in a single call.

Comment: this is not possible at least logically basically in script1 you have `myGlobalVariable` of type X and script2 running alongside script1 which has `myGlobalVariable` as type Y. I mean a variable cannot represent 2 states at the same time (except in quantum physics)

Comment: @TachibanaShin if you look at the title of my question, it makes more sense

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to setup a Typescript project with multiple source dirs and separate compile destinations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68195354/how-to-setup-a-typescript-project-with-multiple-source-dirs-and-separate-compile) or [Preventing inappropriate imports and enforcing project hierarchy in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61241866/8910547)