# TypeScript path aliases stopped working with project references

Tags: typescript, alias, package.json, tsconfig, tsc

Previously, i was facing a issue about `package.json` not being under `rootDir`, but then, i could find a [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753163/package-json-is-not-under-rootdir) addressing the exact same issue, after following the steps suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467483/9182121) i ended up having my path aliases unrecognized by `tsc` when trying to generate declaration files by running `tsc --build src`

> **Notice:** I didn't included declaration related properties on `tsconfig.json` like `"declaration": true` or `"emitDeclarationOnly": true` because i couldn't even transpile the code at first, and i'm focused on getting path aliases to work as they seem to be a more complex and separated problem from `.d.ts` generation, if this come to be a issue, i include later in a comment on this same issue

**File structure:**

```
.
├── src/
│   ├── helpers/
│   │   └── parseOptions.ts
│   ├── eswatch.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

**`./tsconfig.json`**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "composite": true,
  },
  "files": ["package.json"],
}
```

**`./src/tsconfig.json`**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "../types",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "paths": {
    "@eswatch/*": ["./*"]
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "../" }
  ]
}
```

Path aliases are not being recognized at all when used in conjunction to project references, indeally, they should work as normal, and consequently, the declaration files should be emitted

Comment: Why do you have 2 tsconfig.json ?

Comment: Due to what was suggested on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467483/9182121)

Comment: Not that weird tbh, it's pretty common in monorepo scenarios and besides that, it's a built-in [typescript feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html), so, it's intended to be used when needed, and no, i'm not adhering to things like reading the `package.json` using node native `fs` module or some ugly hack like that

Comment: Why do you want to read package.json in your app?

Comment: Display the version field when the `-v` or `--version` flag is passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! and turns out it was a really dumb mistake that somehow went unnoticed, the `paths` property of `tsconfig.json` should be inside `compilerOptions` instead of being at object root level, the following works for me:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "../types",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
       "@eswatch/*": ["./*"]
     }
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "../" }
  ]
}
```