# copy package.json while building js library with parcel js

Tags: javascript, typescript, parceljs

I am creating a typescript library, and when I am bundling it with parcel.js, the `package.json` file is not getting copied into the `dist` folder. Can any one let me know how can it be done?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55753163/package-json-is-not-under-rootdir/61467483#61467483

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this by using the [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) package and modifying your build script to copy the `package.json` file to the `dist` folder after parcel runs. (e.g. `parcel build && copyfiles package.json dist`).

However, the reason why parcel doesn't support this out of the box is that you probably don't want to do this. When you're making and publishing an npm library, there are a number of fields in your `package.json` that have special meaning - especially `"main"`, but also `"types"` and `"module"`. When you publish your library, you want to make sure that these fields point to the right thing.

When you run `parcel build`, parcel [looks at these these fields in your `package.json` to decide where to put the output files](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/library/#project-setup).

So if you then copied your unmodified `package.json` file to the `dist` folder and tried to publish the `dist` folder as if it were your package, things would be broken for your users - the `package.json`'s `main` field would point to `dist/outputbundle.js`, but the actual file would be at `/bundleoutput.js`.

If you want publish only a subset of the files in your project, the typical way to do this is to use the `package.json` `files` field to "whitelist" which folders get included when you run `npm publish`, without modifying the package structure (see [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#files)).